# How to disable button when loading table rows in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I’m using JQuery with HTML to create a button that when clicked, loads table rows.

My HTML:

```
<div class="load-more-container">
<button id="btn-load-more">Load More</button>
</div>
<p id="loading" style="display:none"> Loading ... </p>
```

My js:

```
$("#btn-load-more").on("click", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#btn-load-more").prop("disabled", true)
   $("#loading").show();
   //loading table rows
   $("#btn-load-more").prop("disabled", false)
   $("#loading").hide();
})
```

I want my button to be disabled when I click on it, and a “Loading…” text will be displayed.

After loading finishes, I want to enable my button again and hide the “Loading…” text.

Currently, the “Loading…” text is only shown after the rows are loaded and not when the rows are loading(my intent).

Can anyone advice me on what’s wrong with my js? Appreciate it!

**Edit:**
Here is a minimum reproducible example. The Loading p tag is not showing when I click on the button with the provided JS code.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#my-table-tbody tr").slice(2).hide()
  if ($("#my-table-tbody tr:hidden").length == 0){
    $("#btn-load-more").hide()
  }

  $("#btn-load-more").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#loading").show();


    $("#my-table-tbody tr:hidden").slice(0,2).slideDown("fast", function(){
      $("#loading").hide();
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
<table id="my-table">

<thead>

<tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button id="btn-load-more" style="cursor: pointer">Load More</button>

    
<p id="loading" style="text-align:center; display:none"> Loading ... </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Remember that javascript is *single-threaded* - this means it can only do one thing at a time and that *includes updating the UI*.   So whenever you have code that does "disable-dosomething-enable" - the "disable" will never occur as it will be enabled before being updated.    You need to show your loader, then *initiate* the loading (eg with a settimeout) and then hide the loader when loading has completed.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks, I have a question as to your implementation. How will I know how much time to set for settimeout an do I initiate the loading in the button onclick function?

Comment: I wasn't clear:  `showLoader(); setTimeout(loadRows, 1);`  `function loadRows() { .... hideLoader(); }` - don't close the loader on the timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what this "line of code" actually does:

```
//loading table rows
```

If this is a synchronous operation (such as building a bunch of HTML from data you already have) then there isn't much you can do.  JavaScript is single-threaded, so this process:

1. Change the UI to "loading"
2. Perform synchronous, CPU-intensive operation
3. Change the UI to "not loading"

This will result in no *visual* appearance of the first UI update, because the thread is busy performing all of the other operations and then processing the second UI update.  So by the time the screen re-draws, only the latest UI is seen.

***However***, if "loading table rows" is an *asynchronous* process (such as fetching data via AJAX), then you certainly can temporarily show something in the UI.  In this case it depends on how you structure that asynchronous operation.

Since nothing here is `async` then I assume we're not using `async` and `await`.  The use of jQuery here suggests a callback-based structure.  In that case the second UI update would just need to go in that callback.

For example, if we substitute your asynchronous operation with something simple like `setTimeout` just to demonstrate, we see how we can put that code in the callback:

```js
$("#btn-load-more").on("click", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   // 1: Show the loader
   $("#btn-load-more").prop("disabled", true)
   $("#loading").show();

   // 2: Invoke the asynchronous operation, whatever it may be
   setTimeout(function () {

       // 3: Hide the loader
       $("#btn-load-more").prop("disabled", false)
       $("#loading").hide();

   }, 3000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="load-more-container">
  <button id="btn-load-more">Load More</button>
</div>
<p id="loading" style="display:none"> Loading ... </p>
```

Here we see that the "Loading" state is displayed for 3 seconds and then removed.  Whatever your *asynchronous* operation is, you'd essentially structure the code as:

1. Change the UI to "loading"
2. Invoke the asynchronous operation
3. *In the calllback*, change the UI to "not loading"

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! If my loading of table rows is simply just `$("#table-tbody tr:hidden").slice(0,50).slideDown()` to reveal previous table rows that were hidden, is it a synchronous operation since the elements are already present in the HTML in the first place?

Comment: @codingismypassion: Take a look at [the documentation for `slideDown`](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) in that case, particularly the part about the callback function to be invoked when the animation completes.  Structurally that's no different from the example above.

Comment: I have actually given`slidedown` a try. However, if i include the showing of the loader in the callback function, the loader is only shown after the slidedown event is completed and not during the sliding down action.

Comment: @codingismypassion: The idea is to show the loader *before* the operation, and then *hide* the loader in the callback (which happens *after* the operation).  Showing the loader after the operation wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: I got the rough idea, basically once a selector is being executed, the other selector must wait for the first to complete? (correct me if I'm wrong, so in this case the button's operation has to complete before my loader even shows, so I have to show the loader before the operation?) However, it makes no sense for a loader to be shown before I click the button?

Comment: @codingismypassion: *Selectors* aren't the issue here.  It's the operations you're performing.  Whether this happens when clicking a button or any other time doesn't really matter either.  The sequence of operations for something like this is: (1) Show the loader.  (2) Start the asynchronous process (in this case the "slide down").  (3) Hide the loader.  Where you put that third step is key.  It needs to happen *after the asynchronous operation completes*.  In the case of a callback structure like this one, you'd put it in that callback.  Do you have an example you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250558/discussion-between-codingismypassion-and-david).

Comment: @codingismypassion: Regarding the question edit... *"However the loader does not show when I click on the button."* - [It does for me](https://jsfiddle.net/duc3m2sg/).  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi, I have added it to the edit!

Comment: @codingismypassion: I've converted that edit into a runnable stack snippet.  Running the code shows no UI elements at all.  How exactly are you interacting with this UI?  Did you actually *test* this [mcve] before including it?  Please clarify the exact problem you are observing in this example.